# Ubuntu 12.04 Black Screen

Tags: boot, grub2

I have only Ubuntu 12.04 on my system. 
After I installed some updates, I restarted and the boot sequence would skip the GRUB Menu and go straight to the first option (normal Ubuntu boot).

Even if I press <kbd>Shift</kbd> or <kbd>Space</kbd>, it would not load. 
It would start to load the Ubuntu logo, then go black.

If I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> then I am able to login, and run some commands, but if I go to the graphical mode (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd>) then it is stuck in the picture shown here.

I want to boot via the recovery mode.

[image: http://tinypic.com/r/33eiyd3/5]

I haven't tried boot-recovery, but I will. Anything else I can do?

update #1: I removed timidity, and restarted (in hindsight, timidity wasn't the problem as it was the last thing that had [OK] next to it). Now it boots, but it goes into a black screen after it displays the Ubuntu logo, right before it is supposed to go into desktop. It's not a black-screen-no-signal thing, it is like the background is all black. I tried booting from USB, and the same thing happened. I am slightly annoyed, because there is no apparent reason for this. Now I can't even go into the terminal. I would be happy to receive any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what kind is your video card, you can try this:

```
  sudo su
  wget http://smxi.org/sg/sgfxi
  chmod +x sgfxi
  ./sgfxi
```

This script is designed to help installing Nvidia/AMD proprietary drivers automatically downloading them from vendor's site.
I suspect kernel was updated.

Comment: At the end, I solved it. I was a problem with the display manager.

Answer (score 0):

I am copying this from my other (more recent) post on a later Ubuntu version,hopefully this can help someone in the future:  [Ubuntu boots to black screen with cursor after upgrade (from 18.04 to 20.04)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1279976/ubuntu-boots-to-black-screen-with-cursor-after-upgrade-from-18-04-to-20-04/1279979#1279979)

I would try to re-install the GUI / Desktop:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
sudo apt autoremove

sudo apt remove ubuntu-desktop
sudo apt autoremove
sudo apt install ubuntu-desktop
```

or

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-gnome-desktop
```

Edit: related Reinstall Gnome

2nd Edit:

> Just in case this wouldn't work for someone in the future:
>
> ```
> You can always try to install another (different) GUI/Desktop: Like LXDE, and from there (when you have a working GUI/Desktop) Maybe
> ```
>
> try different things?
>
> Extremely glad it worked and that I could help!
>
> Note: I have noticed that
>
> ```
> This seems to be a very, very common problem (Because I have often, and some of my friends - had this problem, some other problem
> ```
>
> that (in my case) was after this worked; was the Ubuntu was laggy, but
> in my case it resolved itself to just, install drivers & update the OS
> and reboot. (In case this would be the issue after, this could be a
> good thing to try)