# Ubuntu boots to black screen with cursor after upgrade (from 18.04 to 20.04)

Tags: boot, gui, desktop-environments, .desktop, firmware

it says firmware load failed then boots to a black screen, if you do Ctrl alt F4 it opens a non gui terminal.

Comment: Good you added the little detail that you can indeed access a terminal. It helped a lot.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Ok, so I would try to re-install the GUI / Desktop:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
sudo apt autoremove

sudo apt remove ubuntu-desktop
sudo apt autoremove
sudo apt install ubuntu-desktop
```

or

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-gnome-desktop
```

or. one could try
`sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-gnome-desktop`

or whatever desktop you have
(can be xfce4, kde,  or something else **although** I have not tried all of the options, but xfce4 *seems* to work flawless.)

Edit: related [Reinstall Gnome](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1257470/reinstall-gnome)

**Just in case this wouldn't work for someone in the future:**

- You can always try to install another (different) GUI/Desktop: Like LXDE, and from there (when you have a working GUI/Desktop) Maybe try different things?

**Extremely glad it worked and that I could help!**

Note: I have noticed that

- *This seems to be a very, very common problem (Because I have often, and some of my friends - had this problem, some other problem that (in my case) was after this worked; was the Ubuntu was laggy, but in my case it resolved itself to just, install drivers & update the OS and reboot.

  (In case this would be the issue after, this could be a good thing to try)*

#### Edit: If some has problems with installing drivers

(e.g Nvidia) I would highly suggest checking out [Smaili's Great answer here -](https://askubuntu.com/a/1276794/1130604)  (Since it's the same version, too - and driver problems can often come after a solution like this above)

Thanks!

regards.

Comment: This is just the best answer ever. I was going to reinstall whole fresh copy since it happened to me twice and this solution is genius. Thank you so much

Comment: thanks; it means a lot! @wbadry