# I have a problem with Ubuntu

Tags: grub2, recovery-mode

I use Linux, installed the Ubuntu distribution, as it is based on it.

Now I decided to play around with wine and put a couple of toys from Windows, installed wine and lutris. I installed Vulkan driver for Intel graphics cards to run some programs.

I wrote down some other commands for Intel, to be honest, I don't remember what I wrote, and after restarting the laptop, the system stopped starting.

The motherboard boot appears, the Ubuntu logo appears, and then just a black screen with a blinking cursor. And so on ad infinitum.

BUT the system was able to start up through the mod recovery. More precisely, when I load the recovery mod, I press to start the system normally in the same place, and everything loads and works as usual.

I tried to reinstall the operating system, I downloaded Ubuntu to the USB flash drive, but it does not start up. Constantly throws some kind of error. I don't have any additional drivers, maybe black screen because of this?

Comment: Blow it away and reinstall.

Comment: If you could boot into Ubuntu then try the boot repair tool. https://www.howtogeek.com/114884/how-to-repair-grub2-when-ubuntu-wont-boot/. In your case you might need to boot from usb and try this.

Comment: We don't know what release (and/or *flavor*) you're asking about, nor what type of hardware you're using.  You can view your command history via <kbd>Up</kbd> at terminal, or the command `history` which usually provides clues on fixing issues (ie. what you did which is a start at reversing it). Next you can look at logs for clues (`/var/log/apt/history.log` shows *deb* packages installed/removed) etc.  But I'd start with your OS & release & some hardware details possibly.

Comment: You need to be much more precise. Which commands did you run, what error appears etc. We can't help you if you don't remember which commands you run or don't specify the errors you get.

Comment: @Bakh Desh Welcome to askUbuntu! Is this (both helpful and) related? https://askubuntu.com/questions/1279976/ubuntu-boots-to-black-screen-with-cursor-after-upgrade-from-18-04-to-20-04/1279979#1279979  If yes,  does it help solve your problem?  Best Wishes!

Comment: Adding another comment to write clearly: first line I would recommend trying:               `re-install the GUI / Desktop...`  (From the link I (**above**) provided)