# After boot black screen with cursor after switching to new laptop [20.04]

Tags: boot, dual-boot, drivers, grub2, nvidia

I need your help. I have no idea what to do next to avoid reinstalling system from the scratch to make it working.
So from the beginning. I bought new laptop so I just removed ssd with ubuntu 20.04 on my old laptop and install it on the new one. I got small problems with grub etc but it has been fixed. Here are the steps which I did.

**1. I had to fix fstab file at the beginning.**

```
/dev/nvme0n1p1: UUID="2C2A-50CA" TYPE="vfat" PARTUUID="0b79cd40-c65a-4aef-83b0-c0adfd2d3ac0"
/dev/nvme0n1p2: UUID="6c7bb467-2c54-488c-94ee-f5d9e106fa69" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="8c1204fe-df8c-4abb-9b1b-37a6b86f8cf7"
/dev/nvme1n1p1: LABEL="ESP" UUID="1499-AF35" TYPE="vfat" PARTLABEL="EFI system partition" PARTUUID="3f55457e-fa64-45f3-8344-983ed15200ff"
/dev/nvme1n1p3: TYPE="BitLocker" PARTLABEL="Basic data partition" PARTUUID="cda39ef9-b52a-4a2b-836a-181fe9a62861"
/dev/nvme1n1p4: TYPE="BitLocker" PARTLABEL="Basic data partition" PARTUUID="7a350db5-3c56-4ceb-8cfd-4ff8d0ab391a"
/dev/nvme1n1p5: LABEL="WINRETOOLS" UUID="60E0099AE0097794" TYPE="ntfs" PARTUUID="53e24002-a01f-4f7c-9aeb-071c93c07758"
/dev/nvme1n1p6: LABEL="DELLSUPPORT" UUID="44280477280469EE" TYPE="ntfs" PARTUUID="c7071185-7e1c-4f31-b3f7-657a8d84f898"
/dev/sda1: LABEL="UBUNTU 20_0" UUID="964F-EEA7" TYPE="vfat" PARTUUID="008e5f92-01"
```

my fstab file:

```
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/nvme0n1p2 during installation
#/dev/sda5 /mnt/sda6 auto nosuid,nodev,nofail 0 0
UUID=6c7bb467-2c54-488c-94ee-f5d9e106fa69 /               ext4    defaults 1       1
# /boot/efi was on /dev/nvme0n1p1 during installation
#UUID=2C2A-50CA  /boot/efi       vfat    umask=0077      0       1
/swapfile                                 none            swap    sw              0       0
#/dev/disk/by-uuid/01D62093B5438230 /mnt/sda6 auto nosuid,nodev,nofail,x-gvfs-show 0 0
#UUID=2C2A-50CA  /boot/efi       vfat    defaults      0       1
#UUID=2C2A-50CA  /boot/efi       vfat    defaults      0       1
#UUID=2C2A-50CA  /boot/efi       vfat    defaults      0       1
#UUID=2C2A-50CA  /boot/efi       vfat    defaults      0       1
UUID=1499-AF35  /boot/efi       vfat    defaults      0       1
```

**2. Then I reinstall grub**

**3. Then I reinstall nvidia drivers**

I had followed steps from this question: [Blank screen after installing nvidia restricted driver](https://askubuntu.com/questions/41681/blank-screen-after-installing-nvidia-restricted-driver)

**4. Then I reinstall gnome**

In this case I had followed steps from this question:
[Ubuntu boots to black screen with cursor after upgrade (from 18.04 to 20.04)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1279976/ubuntu-boots-to-black-screen-with-cursor-after-upgrade-from-18-04-to-20-04)

**5. I did fsck command to find and repair**

Unfortunately I still got black screen with cursor after grub menu. Any idea what is wrong and how I can fix it?

Comment: SSD transplants rarely work as one would hope. That said, you may be able to get some indication of the failure(s) by booting from a Live USB, mounting the internal storage device, and accessing the logs in `/var/log`. From there you can dig into each error to determine if it makes more sense to resolve the issues one by one or start fresh 

Comment: If it's a desktop install (you didn't say), you can re-install rather quickly (no-format) and your additional (or *manually installed*) packages will be auto-reinstalled, and user files/configs also untouched; as long as you don't format.  Installs don't need to be from *scratch*  (if it's server install; as system directories are wiped & re-created, server apps will lose their configs; so as always ensure you have a good backup before hand)